# How to trigger axios.interceptor to intercept a request when refreshing a token

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, jwt, refresh-token

I am currently working on an axios interceptor that triggers before a GET request. The idea is to check if the logged in user's refresh token has expired, and if so it should be refreshed.

I have an LoginForm.jsx file that has the login functionality as well as the refresh token functionality which is seen below:

```
function LoginForm() {

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    //end point for registration
    const registerUrl = "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register";

    const loginUrl = "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login";

    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        accessToken: "",
        refreshToken: ""
    })

   
    
   
    const refreshToken = async () => {
        try{
            console.log("in refreshToken func");
            console.log("before passing refresh, refresh is:");
            console.log(Cookies.get('refresh'));

            //refresh cookie is reaching here
            //the 403 is due to an invalid token being passed here

            //an old token is being passed which is causing 403, which means the res.data is not updated
            const res = await axios.post(refreshUrl, {token: Cookies.get('refresh')});
            setUser({
                ...user,
                accessToken: res.data.accessToken,
                refreshToken: res.data.refreshToken,
            });
            //not reaching here some times so it is an issue with the post itself?
            console.log("user is");
            console.log(user);
            return res.data;
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }



 
    
    const axiosJWT = axios.create(); 


    axiosJWT.interceptors.request.use(async (config)=>{
    //     //before making a request
        console.log("in axios.interceptors")
        let currentDate = new Date();
        if(!Cookies.get('authorization')){
            console.log("no access token")
            return;
        }
        
        //check if this already exists
        const decodedToken = jwt_decode(Cookies.get('authorization'));
        console.log("decode expiry is:")
        console.log(decodedToken.exp);


        //if the token has expired
        if(decodedToken.exp * 1000 < currentDate.getTime()){
            console.log("refreshing token!")
            const data = await refreshToken();
            console.log(" refresh token data is");
            console.log(data);
            // config.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + data.accessToken;
            Cookies.set('authorization', data.accessToken);
            Cookies.set('refresh', data.refreshToken);
        }
        return config;
    },(error)=>{

        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

The axios.interceptors.request is intended to run and then generate the refresh token when certain requests are made, like getting products. My issue is that the GET request lives on a file called products.jsx which has none of the login or token functionality on it.:

```
 const axiosNew = axios.create();

 


    useEffect(()=>{

        // FUNCTION TO GET PRODUCTS
        const getProducts = async () =>{
            try{
                //run the axios.interceptor to genereate the token before this request
                const res = await axiosNew.get(
                    cat
                    ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products?category=${cat}` 
                    // : "http://localhost:5000/api/products");
                    : "http://localhost:5000/api/products", { headers: {"token" : "Bearer "+Cookies.get('authorization')} });
```

The file paths are:
/components/LoginForm.jsx and
/components/Products.jsx

How would I be able to trigger the axios.interceptors on LoginForm.jsx when making a get request on Products.jsx ?

Thanks